# How do I ensure Inkscape preserves whitespace when converting PDF text to SVG

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape to convert single page PDF files to SVG files (on Windows).

All the text from the PDF is converting successfully and is appears on the page exactly as it does in the input, except for the whitespace.  The SVG files look the same as the input documents because the text is positioned correctly by the 'x' attributes in the 'tspan' elements but the inner text of the tspan doesn't have the whitespace from the PDF.

For instance if I highlight these three words in the PDF and paste them, they appear as:

```
Associated MET Office
```

However, in the resultant SVG I get this:

```
<tspan
     x="0 5.0025001 8.7524996 12.5025 16.672501 20.422501 22.0875 26.2575 28.342501 32.512501 38.48 44.727501 49.73 56.110001 61.945 64.029999 66.114998 67.779999 71.529999"
     y="0"
     id="tspan940">AssociatedMETOffice</tspan>
```

I'm converting the PDF from the command line using the arguments:

```
-z --export-plain-svg
```

So, the whitespace appears to be in the PDF but gets dropped by Inkscape.  I've searched in vain for a preserve whitespace command line option, does such an option exist?

Comment: Copy-and-pasting text from a PDF does not necessary reflect what's *inside* the PDF; the text fragment could carry specialized markup "for copying only". It's also possible the copy routine in your PDF viewer recognizes some large horizontal move between two characters as a space where Inkspace does not. In all honesty, only conjecture is possible without seeing the PDF (and when you *do* know, you'd have to talk to Inkscape's programmers).

Comment: Please share the PDF to analyze.

Comment: mkl asked for the source PDF.  It can be found here: http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadbasic/pamslight-1EA7853C78ADE206A8C31818D7A6BCDE/7FE5QZZF3FXUS/EN/AIP/AD/EG_AD_2_EGTR_en_2014-08-21.pdf

Comment: This PDF contains the text strings `(Associated)`, `(MET)`, `(Office)` placed on absolute positions. Therefore, it needs strict (and accurate) analyzing to detect it's actually one string separated by spaces -- they do not appear in the file. It must be an error or oversight inside Inkscape and/or its SVG export.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for your help.Given what you've said I'd have expected the SVG to produce 3 tspans not 1 (but still be missing the spaces since they're not in the text in the PDF).  I'll take this up with the people that build the PDF as well as reporting a bug on the Inkscape bug tracker.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've found a solution which has worked for the small number of samples I've tried...  I opened up the PDF in Acrobat Pro and had it "Add tags" (View --> Tools --> Accessibility --> Add Tag to Document).  After that the SVG conversion gets the whitespace I expect.

Answer (score -2):

try changing this:

```
x="0 5.0025001 8.7524996 12.5025 16.672501 20.422501 22.0875 26.2575 28.342501 32.512501 38.48 44.727501 49.73 56.110001 61.945 64.029999 66.114998 67.779999 71.529999"
```

to this:

```
x="0"
```

Comment: How would that fix the problem as written in the question?